# Adding encoding in postscript, ghostscript renders text correctly, but converting to PDF does not show the characters

Tags: pdf, arabic, postscript

We have to construct a postscript file that contains Arabic text, so as English text.

GhostScript shows the Arabic text correctly, but converting it to pdf does not show the Arabic letters.

PS file contains the following:

```
    /TraditionalArabic findfont dup
    length dict
    copy begin

    /Encoding Encoding 256 array copy def
    Encoding 1 /kafinitialarabic put
    Encoding 2 /behinitialarabic put
    Encoding 3 /yehmedialarabic put
    Encoding 4 /seenfinalarabic put
    Encoding 5 /eacute put
    Encoding 6 /a put

    /ArabicTradDict currentdict definefont pop

    end
    %%Page: 1 1
    %%BeginPageSetup
    %%PageMedia: Color Weight Type
    << /MediaColor (Blue)/MediaWeight 75 /MediaType () /xx {2.803464567 mul} def /xx           {2.83464567 mul} def  /PageSize [240 xx 345 xx]>> setpagedevice
    %%EndPageSetup
    /ArabicTradDict  18 selectfont

    72 xx 300 xx moveto
    (\004\003\002\001) show
    showpage
```

To run ghostScript: running it from command line to include all windows fonts:

```
    gswin64.exe -sFONTPATH=%windir%/fonts -dEmbedAllFonts=true
```

To convert the PS file to PDF file: running the following command:

```
   gswin64.exe -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -         sOutputFile=c:/Users/mob/Desktop/TimesNewRomanPSMT.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -  dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dCompressFonts=false -dSubsetFonts=false -sFONTPATH=%windir%/fonts -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -f c:/Users/mob/Desktop/TimesNewRomanPSMT.ps
```

So when converting to PDF, the Arabic characters are not showing correctly, but showing as squares that are of no meaning...

If I use Adobe tool to convert to PDF, the PDF we get is same, except the "eacute -(005) " if included in the PS file, will show after conversion, where as when I convert with the previous command line, all characters that are added from the Encoding are not shown correctly.

Any help with that?

Comment: Even if the font is Courier or Times, anything that is added from the defined characters that are included under the encoding does not render correctly when converted to PDF... so its not in this case exactly about font selection (maybe e acute does not belong to ArabicTraditional font, but when even trying letter a, which is included in Times, if added through this way of encoding, in PDF it is not rendered correctly), but somewhere else which I apparently can not know about...

Comment: How about posting an example which uses a standard font, I don't have a font called 'TraditionalArabic' and you say that using Courier or Times doesn't work, so why not post an example using one of those ? NB the 'squares' are the TrueType .notdef glyph which suggests that your font is a TrueType font. There is no specification for PostScript to use TrueType fonts directly, so in the case of this font it is possible that your re-encoding simply won't work. However Courier et al should.

Comment: I tried that with Courier and Helvetica, both work for me (obviously not using the arabic glyphs, I used /A)

Comment: @KenS Thanks. I have actually used Times-Roman and added only one character which is the letter a, so i used (006)  as you see it is the 6th in the encoding. It showed correctly in ghostscript, and in pdf. I was mistaken in my first post, the english letter a did not show because I was using TraditionalArabic. But, arabic characters are showing with that font with encoding in ghostscript, but not in pdf!... you might -would be thankful- install the Traditional Arabic font, which is a windows font, and try that. So my first post wasnt correct, probably because i used arabic font for english?!

Comment: Basically, you can't do this with a TrueType font. TrueType fonts aren't usable in PostScript (at least not as TrueType fonts, you can use a type 42 font), so in  order to allow their use Ghostscript does some trickery behind the scenes. The result of this is that only a certain set of glyph names is available, and the Arabic names are not among them. If you want to use an Arabic TrueType font, you'll have to make it into a type 42 font and include it in your PostScript.

Comment: so how can i get type 42 font from a true type font?! I am using windows 7 64bit. I have googled it but it looks like there are tools for linux to do that like ttf2pf...

Comment: @kenS, I have solved my problem, the mistake was that behinitialarabic in my encoding was wrong, it should have been behinitial. How I knew it? i converted traditional arabic ttf to afm, and looked in the generated pfa file, it was behinitial. so i replaced that in my ps file and it converted correctly to pdf. If you would add your comments in an answer, then I would mark it as ur answer ;). Thanks!

Comment: I'm surprised that worked at all, none of the arabic glyphs worked for me, but I'm glad its OK for you.

Comment: @MoB Since you solved the problem, perhaps *you* should write the answer. This is perfectly fine on this site. ... By the way, in your code, definitions like `/xx {2.803464567 mul} def` which go into the current dictionary look very strange when inside the `<<` dictionary construct `>>`. It would be better style to do that on a separate line (and only *once* is enough). HTH. +1 for an interesting topic.

Comment: @luser droog: You are right about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to KenS hints I was able to solve my problem. The encoding used wrong character names like kafinitialarabic (i mean by wrong, pdf could not understand that), everything that ended with arabic was wrong. The Traditional Arabic font does not have those names for characters. In order to know what it really understood, have converted the ttf font to afm and pfa using the following command, that is converting the true type font to type 42 font which will be understood once embed in postscript file at conversion to pdf

```
    C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.10\bin>gswin64c.exe -dNODISPLAY -q -- ttf2pf.ps times tim
    esPS timesAFM
```

where times is the ttf font name. I then checked the generated pfa file for the characters I wanted to add, instead of kafinitialarabic, there was kafinitial, and for kafmedialarabic there was kafmedial and so on...

It works fine now to add those in encoding, but I want to find a way instead of adding all those characters in the dictionary, I want to use the font like we use with setfont in postscript normally - if that is possible...

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested, you need to ensure the glyph names you use are in the font you use, or create a new font.

I haven't found anything that will choose the correct glyph from the set of initial, medial, final, isolated, depending on context, though.

I resorted to writing a program which takes unicode arabic, reverses it the arabic characters, and then decides which tone of character to use based on it's position in a word, and whether the previous or next characters are forced into isolated or final forms. Unfortunately had to embed quite some intrinsic knowledge about the font in use and the glyph names it has, as well as typos in them, into the program.

If that's of interest, I've stuck it on github, but it's very raw and initial.
It *does* work, though.

https://github.com/gbjk/arabic2ps

The font I used was a traditional arabic font, with quite a few idiosyncrasies.